# .NET forms for SharePoint 2010 without InfoPath

Tags: development, .net

Afternoon all,

Can anyone advise if it's possible to create forms for SharePoint 2010 Standard (to submit to a list) without using InfoPath?  My version of the product doesn't have InfoPath Services.

I'm making my first moves into learning SharePoint Development and this requirement is a good starting point.  I have previously customised EditForm / NewForm but would like to take my learning one step further.

Many thanks,
Steven

Comment: Check out this [question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26015/sharepoint-lists-editform-dispform), I think this is something you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can create customer ASPX application pages pretty easily using Visual Studio. It is a process, however, too much to walk through here. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231581(v=vs.100).aspx for a great start. Come back if you get stuck ;)

HTH

Comment: Dont think this will work for SharePoint online. I have a very similar situation to the above but everything will be deployed to SP online, is there an alternative for this scenario?

Comment: David / Kai, I'm checking out both these responses now.  I'll have a crack and will mark up an answer accordingly.  Thanks for providing the links.

Comment: SP online is def different. 2010 or 2013? 2010 you can get away with sandbox projects, which limits your access to some server APIs. 2013 has the new app model, all client side dev, no server side code on SP.

Answer (score 1):

I used Custom List forms created in SharePoint Designer exclusively when we were on WSS 3.0. I wrote my own custom validation scripts, CSS and spruced them up to be more dynamic than Infopath forms. It did involve more work initially to write the JavaSrcript files and CSS for consistent appearance and function for all of our forms. But the markup is way better then SP's table love. jQuery was also a huge benefit in making the forms super-dynamic, think Web 2.0. You can modify your custom forms from the generated XSLT in SP Designer or write your own HTML, JavaScript with SPServices for submission and if you really want to get fancy and you need to bind JSON to your fields, use Knockout.js or Backbone.js for your MVC. I often duplicated InfoPath's ability to import data sources from other data sources. For instance a one-to-many parent list to a child list with editable transactions within a single approval form. Each item had it's own jQueryUI dialog box with an attachment field. Once my framework was in place, all forms after that went up quick. InfoPath is a great tool but I like the control I have writing my own UI code.

Comment: Hi Ra88l thanks for your response.  The advanced customisation of the OOB forms is what I was hoping to avoid but it does offer more power.  I'd not heard of Knockout.js or Backbone.js before though!  Thanks for the references.

Comment: Here is a solution - https://github.com/jbonfardeci/ShockoutForms

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a comprehensive framework that combines the power of Knockout JS data binding with SharePoint REST services for truly modern and dynamic SharePoint forms without the headache of InfoPath or XSLT. I call it "Shockout" and you can download it from Git Hub at https://github.com/jbonfardeci/ShockoutForms